# Rotate Icons in a circle by finger

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, core-animation, uiimageorientation

I have a project having the home page like the attached image and need to implement the following functionality.

Home Page slides in left to right 
Functionality of this is the icons rotate in a circle by finger
Sliding once user clicks on an icon they will be directed to the page.

Pls help someone, if you have done such things.

Regards
CJ

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the Custom `UICollectionView` Layout may help you to best fit your requirement.

[image]

[Download the source code and reference from here.](https://github.com/awdigital/AWCollectionViewDialLayout)

Comment: @cjiosdeveloper is it helps to you or not?

Comment: No this is not workable, need to implement this url technique in this case http://www.code4app.net/ios/This-is-a-rotating-menu,-it-is-very-convenient-to-use/556ff264e2474107387edbe0. can you break it for me.

Comment: @CJIOSDeveloper as per your question's image provided same example but now you want above kind of example then directly use that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "this URL technique" but that sounds like a new question. You are probably not going to find a library that does everything you want "out of the box". You will need to start with something and then add the features you need.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a library called iCarousel by Nick Lockwood. (Available on Github.) It is very configurable and will give you exactly what you need with very little custom code.